# $\left\{ \frac{n}{m} + \frac{m}{n} \ \ n,m \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$ find sup and inf using lim

Tags: limits, limsup-and-liminf, supremum-and-infimum

$$\left\{ \frac{n}{m} + \frac{m}{n} \ \ n,m \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \ \ 0 \notin \mathbb{N}$$

So for $n=1$ $$\lim_{m \to +\infty} \frac{1}{m} +m = +\infty$$
$$\lim_{m \to 1} \frac{1}{m} +m = 2$$

And for $m=1$ $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{n} +n = +\infty$$
$$\lim_{n \to 1} \frac{1}{n} +n = 2$$

The question is: is this enough to state that $sup = \infty \ $ and $inf = 2$ ?

Comment: You haven't really proven that $2$ is the lower bound. Try showing that $x+\frac{1}{x} \geq 2$, using calculus, quadratic equations, or even the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Hint: The set is $\{u(n/m)\mid n\ge m\ge1\}$ where $u:x\mapsto x+1/x$ is increasing on $x\ge1$ (can you prove this?). It follows that its infimum is $u(1)$ (and also a minimum) and its supremum $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}u(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\dfrac{m}n + \dfrac{n}m \geq 2$$
with equality holding for $m=n$. Hence, the infimum is $2$. For the supremum, fixing $n$, letting $m\to \infty$, we see that
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(\dfrac{m}n+\dfrac{n}m\right) = \infty$$
Hence, the supremum is $\infty$.